# C++ error: redefinition of class

Tags: c++, class, compiler-errors, g++

**Note:** I have searched thoroughly on SO and the solutions posted for other's with similar questions are not working for me here.

I am writing my own custom 'string-like' class in C++, and am encoutering the following errors when compiling:

> ./PyString.h:8:11: error: out-of-line declaration of 'PyString' does
>   not match any declaration in 'PyString' PyString::PyString (char*);
>             ^
>
> ./PyString.h:9:11: error: definition of implicitly declared destructor PyString::~PyString (void);
>
> pystring.cpp:4:7: error: redefinition of 'PyString' class PyString {

As for the first and second errors, moving around the destructor into the class definition itself in the `cpp` file did not work.

As for the third error, I can't seem to fix it - I'm not redefining the class!

Here is `pystring.h`:

```
#ifndef PYSTRING_INCLUDED
#define PYSTRING_INCLUDED

class PyString {
    char* string;
};

PyString::PyString (char*);
PyString::~PyString (void);

#endif
```

Here is `pystring.cpp`:

```
#include "PyString.h"
#define NULL 0

class PyString {
    char* string = NULL;
  public:
    PyString(char inString) {
      string = new char[inString];
    };

    ~PyString(void) {
      delete string;
    };
};
```

For reference, here is the compile output as a screenshot:
[image: Compiler output screenshot]

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you should get [a good beginners book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and start over, because it's not much in your shown source that is correct.

Comment: Look up *any* example of a class defined in a header with its members defined in a `.cpp` file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're defining your class PyString in your header AND in your cpp file, and also, a function definition doesn't need a `;` at it's end.
And... your function prototypes needs to be in your class declaration in your header :

pystring.h

```
class PyString {
public: //ALWAYS indicate what is public/private/protected in your class
    PyString (char* inString);
    ~PyString (); // Don't put void when there's no parameter

private: // All attributes are private
    char* string;
};
```

pystring.cpp

```
#include "PyString.h"

PyString::PyString(char* inString) {
    string = inString; // Avoid using new unless you're forced to
}

PyString::~PyString() {
}
```

Comment: `PyString::` should not be present inside the class definition (it's an error but some compilers let it pass). Also your suggestion for "pystring.c" is completely wrong

Comment: Damn, i'm making a lot of mistakes today... thanks

Comment: I copied both the snippets into separate files, but is says that `PyString::PyString` is an extra qualification. In addition, it still says that there is a redeclaration.

Comment: It won't anymore, idk why people upvoted my wrong answer before this edit....

Comment: @Treycos: And I was *seriously* about to launch my IDE to see if, in total bewilderment, if your previous answer compiled ;-) My upvote is a symptom of my elation in being reassured that I can still do this.

Comment: Oh god, poor complier, thats rude

Comment: Aha, it worked! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Oh yes you are! `pystring.h` contains

```
class PyString {
    char* string;
};
```

which is a class *declaration*. The declarations `PyString::PyString (char*);`
and `PyString::~PyString (void);` need to be inside that declaration.

But you have something similar in `pystring.cpp`, specifying additional functions, and *defining* some of them. That's what your compiler is telling you.

*Normally*, you *fully define* a `class` in a header (i.e. all members, and the declaration of the member functions), and *implement* the member functions of that class in a source file.

The moral of the story here: you can't really learn C++ by trial and error. Get a good book!

Comment: It is also a class *definition*. That is the problem! At least, the problem reported in the title.

Comment: For *fully declare* you mean *fully define* (the class, not the members.)